# Comparing working directory with "string"

Tags: shell-script, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to compare the current working directory's path with my home directory's path.

```
user@machine:~$ echo $PWD
/home/user
user@machine:~$ if ["$PWD" = "/home/user"]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
bash: [/home/user: No such file or directory
False
user@machine:~$ if ["$PWD" = "whatever"]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
bash: [/home/user: No such file or directory
False
```

I expected it to print `True` in the second command and `False` in the third, while not printing `bash: [/home/user: No such file or directory`. Why is it printing this and how do I get it to work as I wanted to?

Comment: There must be spaces between `[` or `]` and the string. Try `if [ "$PWD" = "/home/user" ]; then`... It is printing the error message because it tries to find a command `[/home/user` instead of `[` followed by argument `/home/user`.

Answer (score 4):

you're appending `[` to `$PWD`.

try:

```
user@machine:~$ if [ "$PWD" = "/home/user" ];
```